# Display: Flex item going out of the max width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, display

I have three items (columns) with `display: flex` and `margin-left` set to them. When I resize the window and scroll right they are going out of the box/window (overflowing).
Second problem - the third pic is with different height even though I set `max-height` to it.
Here's just a part of the code (the problem occurs again even here):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.articleContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border-top: 7px solid rgb(227, 0, 26);
  height: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  top: -4px;
  width: 333px;
}

.content img {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 230px;
  width: 333px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(227, 0, 26);
}
```

```html
<div class="background"> </div>

<article>
  <div class="articleContainer">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://i.imgupx.com/VHqKvqVY/metropolis-meltdown.png" width="333px" alt="Metropolis">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="textContent"></div>

      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://i.imgupx.com/wyFIxuMT/metropolis-blue-meltdown.jpeg" width="333px" alt="Metropolis">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="textContent"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://i.imgupx.com/EBvbuJgh/Optimized-PHRANK.jpeg" width="333px" alt="Metropolis">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="textContent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

I've tried `min-width` set to `0` but the columns are overlapping if i do it and `max-height` seems to not resolving the problem with the height of the third pic.

Comment: It is better to put the html, css code in the code snipped provided by the site so that it is easier to see and execute it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the first problem, you can add the following CSS properties to .articleContainer :

```
.articleContainer {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will allow horizontal scrolling when the items go out of the box and also prevent the items from wrapping to the next line and going out of the box.

For the second problem, this problem appears because the aspect ratio of the image is not consistent with the other images. To fix this, you should use a fixed height and width instead of max-height.

```
.content img {
  height: 230px;
  width: 333px;
}
```

I hope this answer is helpful to you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Overflow is fixed but setting height to the images class didnt work and now the columns (.container) are not with the same height even though the container has "top:" property for all of the items.